# How to disable vibration on call in silent mode on a Xiaomi (MIUI 10)

Tags: java, android, xiaomi, miui

I got an Android app that is supposed to mute the phone / activate DND. For all my Androids, that's working perfectly when setting the RingerMode to silent. Except for my Xiaomi running with MIUI 10.

I used this code:

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

When I do so, the silent mode will indeed be enabled on the Xiaomi as well, but unfortunately, there is a default setting in MIUI saying "Vibrate on silent".

I have no idea how to bypass this. I tried also setting all available streams to 0 with the following code, without any luck:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to make this MIUI 10 silent without any vibration when a call comes in?

Thanks a lot!

Philip

Comment: Hello. Have you solved your issue? I am a similar problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.